# what is the difference between 'metadata.labels' and 'spec.template.metadata.labels'

Tags: kubernetes

reading the kubernetes docs, it is not very clear to me what is the difference between
specifying labels at the top-level metadata key, versus at the spec level.

Consider:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginxv1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

which I have copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837981/k8s-significance-of-spec-template-metadata-section , where my google searching landed me.

What's the difference between the two labels that are set in this manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`metadata.labels` sets the labels that apply to **the deployment**.

`spec.template.metadata.labels` sets the labels that apply to **pods management by the deployment**.

The values in `spec.selectors.matchLabels` are used to select pods, so they need to match the labels in `spec.template.metadata.labels`; they have nothing to do with the Deployment's `metadata.labels`.